# Match words with spaces after multiple prefixes

Tags: c#, regex, preg-match

I have the following string

```
D_Doc Name L_Linked Doc Q_1_5
```

or

```
D_Doc Name L_Linked Doc Q_5
```

I'm having a hard time creating a regex to match the following

```
Doc Name
Linked Doc
1_5 or 5
```

D_Doc Name is always present
L_ and Q_ are not

The string may also look like the following

```
D_Doc Name Doc Q_1_5
D_Doc Name Doc Q_5
D_Doc Name L_Linked Doc
```

I would like to be able to reference the matches as 
match['DocName'] or some meaning full way so I know which match is found and which isn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly should the output be from all these cases?

Comment: I would like the match results to have 1 to 3 values.  Basically everything after the prefix and before the next (Doc Name, Linked Doc, 1_5 or 5)

Comment: What about this ? D_Doc Name Doc Q_5 Here you would get Doc Name Doc, 5

Comment: That would be fine as long as I could name the matches and check which ones are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the regex you want is something like:

```
^D_(?<D>.*?)( L_(?<L>.*?))?( Q_(?<Q>.*))?$
```

It produces the following results for some test inputs:

```
Input                          D             L           Q 
D_Doc Name L_Linked Doc Q_1_5  Doc Name      Linked Doc  1_5
D_Doc Name Doc Q_1_5           Doc Name Doc              1_5
D_Doc Name Doc Q_5             Doc Name Doc              5
D_Doc Name L_Linked Doc        Doc Name      Linked Doc
D_Doc Name Doc Q_5             Doc Name Doc              5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe regex are a bit too much for this problem, I would use a simple string.Split(s, ' ') and then i'll analyze words one by one, maybe with regex for the last word. Also the last word is easily splittable however. I guess it would be simpler to write your code just working on an array.

Comment: That's what I was thinking and have already started but just wanted to see how powerful regex is or if it's even possible/faster.

Comment: Regex can be very powerful but expressing things in its syntax can be hard and annoying sometime if you are not a regex expert. string.Split is not so bad about performances, these strings are not so big. Writing an optimized regular expression is not easy neither.

Comment: Since your code is full of if i would suggest just the array :)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a little tricky to decipher, but I think this will do it:

`D_(\w+) (\w+) (L_(\w+) )?(\w+)( (Q_)?(\w+))?`

and if you want to add "Named Groups" (with what I assume are appropriate names):

`D_(?<Doc>\w+) (?<DocName>\w+) (L_(?<Linked>\w+) )?(?<LinkedDoc>\w+)( (Q_)?(?<Q>\S+))?`